# A script that sends emails via the OUTLOOK SMTP server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I got a task to do a script in PowerShell where I need to get out of AD a list of names that begin with the letter "A" with full name, username and creation date criteria.
 Then export the list with custom headers and export it to a CSV file
Then import the CSV file again and output anyone who works over two years (full name)
So far I have done the script correctly in my opinion because it works.
Now I'm pretty stuck I need to make every user on the list who went out first to make a folder (no matter where) and give full permissions to the folder - **I did something but it seems to be incorrect.**
Then I need to send an email with a table that states the full name and folder path and that the sender will be no@reply.com.

The code I wrote:

```
 Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=meitavdash,OU=Users,DC=meitav,DC=co,DC=il"

    Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} |Format-Table name,SamAccountName,whenCreated

    Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | Select-Object @{n='FullName';e={$_.Name}},@{n='UserName';e={$_.SamaccountName}},@{n='CreateDate';e={$_.WhenCreated}} |  export-csv -path c:\userexport.csv
    Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | where {$_.whencreated -le (Get-Date).AddYears(-2)}|Select-Object @{n='FullName';e={$_.Name}} 

    $sp=$((Get-Date).AddDays(-365*2)); Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {name -like "A*" -and whenCreated -ge $sp}|%{New-Item -Path "c:\temp" -ItemType Directory; icacls "c:\temp" /T /grant "$($_.samaccountname):(OI)(CI)F"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Send-MailMessage` is your friend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7

Comment: I know I need to use the send-mailmessage command my problem I do not know how to actually create a table with the full name and folder path and calibrate it in the sent email I thought to send a HTML template

Answer (score 0):

As for this...

> "my problem I do not know how to actually create a table with the full
>   name and folder path"

.. is this hat you are after?

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=meitavdash,OU=Users,DC=meitav,DC=co,DC=il'

Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | 
Format-Table name,SamAccountName,whenCreated

Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | 
Select-Object @{
n='FullName';e={$_.Name}},
@{n='UserName';e={$_.SamaccountName}},
@{n='CreateDate';e={$_.WhenCreated}} |  
export-csv -path c:\userexport.csv

Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | 
where {$_.whencreated -le (Get-Date).AddYears(-2)}|Select-Object @{n='FullName';e={$_.Name}} 

$sp=$((Get-Date).AddDays(-365*2))
Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {name -like "A*" -and whenCreated -ge $sp} | 
%{
    $PathUnc = (New-Item -Path 'c:\temp' -ItemType Directory).FullName
    icacls 'c:\temp' /T /grant "$($_.samaccountname):(OI)(CI)F"
}
```